Unable to detect Web Elements in browser stack iPhones
Unable to detect Web Element on iPhone with which ever versions of Appium and selenium are used. Dependencies used.
Selenium Version - 4.13.0
Appium Version - 8.6.0
Kindly help me in proceeding with automation.
